# importing things in java is causing cannot resolve error

Tags: java

[image]

[image]

How to get rid of this error? It's my first time using Java

Comment: You need to import the library. The org.json library is either a library you don't have imported. Or you're trying to import it using wrong path.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Learn to use Maven or Gradle (they're pretty accessible for basic stuff) to manage libraries. And use the Java naming conventions, which are universally standard: Class names start with a capital letter, like `Main`.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Intellij? You will probably have to download the library as a jar and add it to your project.

Comment: And like @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- suggested. It is way easier to import libraries using Maven or Gradle instead of doing this manual jar downloading. I personally prefer Maven, and I'd highly recommend just googling how to set up a Maven (java) project. Also I'd personally recommend you get Intellij over Eclipse. As they have a lot "smart" fixes that just makes things easier. Maybe you're already using it? I can't tell as your window looks different than mine :D

Comment: Also, whenever you start importing libraries (like with Maven), you will see them under external libraries. So as you can see there is no org.json under yours (hence it can't be imported). Hope it helps explain the error :)

Comment: @GamingFelix he is already using Intellij ;)

Comment: Haha, the light mode got me confused. So used to seeing dark mode myself :D

Comment: How do I create the src/main/java folder? I'm unable to add a folder inside src

Comment: Right click on src and add Directory. It might look as if it's not placing it at the right place, but it is.

Comment: There is no option of adding folder. I have updated the post to show the options that come up

Comment: @GamingFelix Eclipse vs. IntelliJ is a pointless holy war. Let's just agree to hate on NetBeans!

Comment: @UddhavBhagat add Package then :)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I will cautiously suggest Intellij nowadays. I wrote about it on social media before and got hunted down by a maintainer of Eclipse :D

Comment: Once I add the package 'main' under 'src', then while I go to add 'java' it adds it under src and not main even though I add it under main

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the external library that you want to use to your project.

To do that, first download the `.jar` file of the library that you want to use. You can find the latest `.jar` release of the `json` library at [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20200518) or on [this github repository](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java).

**In IntelliJ:**

1. Go to **File** -> **Project Structure**
2. Click on **Modules**
3. Click on **Dependencies** tab
4. Click on `+` sign
5. Select **1 JARs or directories**
6. Select the `.jar` file you just downloaded
7. Click **Apply**

Now you can `import org.json.JSONArray;` or `import org.json.JSONObject;` in your project without an error.

**Note:** you should really use some type of dependency management tool like for example `Maven` like others already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project, add framework support, add maven, and inside the pom.xml file that maven created, add the following code:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20200518</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then click the little refresh button inside the maven tab on the right of the screen.
[image]

Now you should be able to use the json library. This is how you use external libraries using maven, it's way faster than importing external jar's manually.

Hope it helps, if you have any other question just leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is you can't import those packages because you don't have them with** you.**To solve this you need add a Jar file externally** which contains those packages.
**Try using a project management tool like Maven**[Commonly use for dependency management] **or try to add that missing Jar files manually** by downloading them through the internet or through the maven central repository.